# Asp.net Core 2.0 Can Not Request *.properites file .Reponse 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, i18next

Hosting with Kestrel.
Request url is http://1270.0.01:9060/lang/order/common.properties.
The file is exist .
Another file http://1270.0.01:9060/lang/order/test.txt can request successfully

I dot not known why ,need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is serving static files, then it's possible that the mime type for .properties needs to be added.

Note: be sure you want to expose .properties to the public.

Have a look at the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` section on this documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

something like this added for .properties:

```
// Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    // Add new mappings
    provider.Mappings[".properties"] = "application/octet-stream";

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        // ...
        ContentTypeProvider = provider
    });
```